# edge-db: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, ..' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, database, edgejs

first of all I'm pretty new to .NET, I've been reading articles and articles for the past few weeks and tried everything I found on the web.

I'm trying to compile edge-db (https://github.com/gaelazzo/edge-db) under .NET >=5 or .NET Core >= 3, I have the same results with both.
The problem is not with the compilation itself, but when it is ran.

This solution is targeting the old .NET Framework (v. 4.5), I had to recreate a new solution, you can find there a version of it, made by gaelazzo:
https://github.com/gaelazzo/edge-db-5 (targets .NET 5.0)

edge-db is meant to be run through edge-sql (https://github.com/gaelazzo/edge-sql)

**I have this error when I run the edge-sql test (using .NET 5 or Core, but of course runs fine with .NET Framework 4.5):**

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've been researching it for days and days, but it's pretty generic. I tried everything I found on the web and tried to find a cause for it, but nothing.
Out of desperation I tried compiling it on a clean windows10 machine, same result, I tried running it there, same result.

Last note: I'm not gaelazzo, the owner of these repositories.

Thank you.

Comment: lib subdirectory.  Never, *never*, **never** copy framework assemblies.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you please clarify? Thank you.
A thing I didn't mention, I tried to copy System.Runtime.dll inside the lib folder, but it doesn't seem to like it:

System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)

Answer (score -1):

if you created your project with netframework 4.8 and then changed it to 3.5, your project will crash with lots of errors, or anything like that (originally created in new version then rolled back to an older version):
you should go to the NuGet Packages, and update anything that is already installed and needs update.